# Change size of outlier labels on boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I have generated two side by side boxplots and labeled the outliers using the car package in R. While this works well, I dont know how to change the size of the outlier labels. I can change the size of the outlier point, but not the label.

Edit: Here is a subset of my data

```
gene    low_cov scaffolds
AA001   10  150
AA002   15  20
AA003   2   160
AA004   20  144
AA005   30  122
AA006   1   80
AA007   50  500
AA008   16  200
AA009   18  164
AA010   4   124
```

Here is my current code:

```
gene = read.csv(file.choose(), header=T, sep='\t', row.names=1)
library(car)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
Boxplot(gene$low_cov, data=gene, labels=row.names(gene), cex=0.2)
Boxplot(gene$scaffolds, data=gene, labels=row.names(gene), cex=0.2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.

Comment: And where does `Boxplot` come from? The base function is `boxplot`.

Comment: I do apologise. Boxplot comes from the example provided here:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf

Comment: The source of `Boxplot` has no way to set the size of just the outlier labels. They seem to only respond to the `par(cex=)` parameter which affects all test on the plot.

Comment: Thank you! You answered my question.
By using:
    par(mfrow=c(1,2), cex=0.4)
I was able to change the size of the outlier labels

Answer (score 5):

You can change the size of the outlier symbols using "outcex". E.g., "outcex=2"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can firstly plot without the outliners, and then manually add them. In that way, you can almost do whatever you want to do to change the style, shape, color, etc. I will use the base function `boxplot` here:

```
> data <- c(10,15,2,20,30,1,50,16,18,4)
> B <- boxplot(data, outline=FALSE, ylim=c(0, 55))
> points(B$group, B$out, type = "p", pch=23)
```

[image]